# Styling text within built-in shiny functions

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to style the text that is displayed by shiny's built-in functions. See the reprex below.

```
library(shiny)
provS <- c("CA","NL","PE","NS","NB","QC","ON","MB","SK","AB","BC","YK","NT","NU")
provL <- c("Canada","Newfoundland and Labrador","Prince Edward Island",
  "Nova Scotia","New Brunswick","Quebec","Ontario","Manitoba","Saskatchewan",
  "Alberta","British Columbia","Yukon","Northwest Territories","Nunavut")
prov <- setNames(provS,provL)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId="province",label=
    tags$b(tags$span(style="color:blue; font-size:26px", "Choose a province:")),
    choices = prov),
  tags$b(tags$span(style="color:blue; font-size:26px",
    "The abbreviation for the selected province is:")),
  textOutput(outputId="provName")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$provName <- renderText({input$province})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example, I would like to display the text displayed inside the `selectInput()` box and the `textOutput()` result in the same blue 26px font used elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply custom css -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(HTML("
  .selectize-input, .option {
    color:blue; 
    font-size:26px
  }
  ")),
  selectInput(inputId="province",label=
                tags$b(tags$span(style="color:blue; font-size:26px", "Choose a province:")),
              choices = prov),
  tags$b(tags$span(style="color:blue; font-size:26px",
                   "The abbreviation for the selected province is:")),
  div(textOutput(outputId="provName"), style="color:blue; font-size:26px")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$provName <- renderText({input$province})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution works very well. I would like to do something similar with radioButtons and other controls, and I imagine this involves changing ".selectize-input" to something else. How/where do I discover the correct names for these controls?

Comment: You should be able to find them if you right click on the app, click on inspect element and using selector gadget find the elements that you need to change.

Comment: That is so helpful Ronak. Thanks very much.